# Help with Cloudpages and Email Forms

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, content-builder

I should start by saying I'm a novice and I'm using the content blocks to create an email. I've created a data extension to capture customers information:

Predefined information from another data extension

- Name
- Email
- Customer number

Radio button

- Confirmation that information is correct

Everything was going great and the Email Form is working as intended but I've hit a hurdle, how do I get around the Email Form block not appearing on certain email clients?

I need to create a Fallback State but how do I do this? What content block should I use here and how do I make sure that the customers date pulls into the data extension like it does when the Email Form is used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your fallback content, define a block that contains a call to action (button, link, image) that takes the user to a [CloudPage](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cp_cloudpages.htm&type=5) where you host a [SmartCapture](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_smart_capture.htm&type=5) that writes to your data extension.

In this way, email clients capable of displaying the Interactive Email form are able to submit directly from the email and all others are invited to visit a similar form in their browser.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Is there a way I can ensure the customer details come across automatically as it will be a hassle for to fill out a form when the information was in the email.

Comment: This is a bit of a vexed question. In principle, add "%%FirstName%%" (or whatever) to the name of the field in your sendable data extension as the value of the form field and it'll pre-populate. The tricky bit is when you've maybe deleted/refreshed the data in your sendable data extension. If that's not a possibility, all good. If you're constantly sending to something like a filtered data extension that's constantly changing the data in the DE, you'll need to look at solutions around Send Logging and using a customised CloudPage.

Comment: Thanks again but as i said I'm a complete novice so where can **sendable data extension as the value of the form field** found?

Comment: That "qs" query string parameter that links to CloudPages when you put together and send your email provides the CloudPage with "context". You can use personalization strings on the page as you would in the email that the consumer clicked though from. It's kind of "automagic". If you have a field in your sendable data extension used for the send called "foo", you can pre-populate a SmartCapture field by setting its value to "%%foo%%".

Comment: Thank you. I have managed to stumble my way through this to get it to work.